# First Stage IV Regression Output in R

Tags: r, instruments, stargazer

I want to report the results of both stages of my Two-Stage Least Square Regression but stargazer output only gives me the second stage.

I have calculated a Two-Stage Least Square Regression with the ivreg command in R.
This is what my code looks like:

```
ivmodel1 <- ivreg(Y ~ X + W1  + W2 + W3 + W4 | W1  + W2 + W3 + W4 + Z, data = df)
```

where

Y = dependent variable (cont.);

X = endogenous independent variable (dummy);

W1-W4 = control variables;

Z = exogenous instrument (dummy)

Now I am having difficulties to report the first stage of the 2SLS regression. 
When I use the usual stargazer command:

```
stargazer(ivmodel1)
```

I only receive the resuts of the second stage but I also need the first stage estimates.
Does someone know what commmand to use in R in order to receive the results of both stages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting first stage results from {AER}'s ivreg()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64122564/getting-first-stage-results-from-aers-ivreg)

Answer (score -1):

When you model each stage separately, you can hand both to `stargazer`:

```
# create sample data frame
set.seed(123)

# observed independent variable (exogenous)
x <- rnorm(100, 3, 15)

# unobserved independent variable (endogenous)
z <- rnorm(100, 3, 7)

# dependent variable
y <- 2 + 3 * x + 4 * z + rnorm(100)

# instrument 
a <- 5 + 7 * z + rnorm(100, 1, 7)

# Combine data
df <- data.frame(x,y,z,a)

# Instrument regression with ivreg
library(ivreg)
iv_reg <- ivreg(y ~ x | z | a, data = df)

# First Stage with lm
first_stage <- lm(z ~ a + x, data = df)
df$first_stage_pred <- predict(first_stage, newdata = df)
cor(df$z, df$first_stage_pred)

# Second Stage with lm
second_stage <- lm(y ~ + x + first_stage_pred, data = df)

# Create latex table
library(stargazer)
stargazer(iv_reg, first_stage, second_stage, type = "text",
          column.labels = c("IVREG", "First STage", "Second Stage"))
```

Final result looks like this:

```
=====================================================================
                                            Dependent variable:          
                                  ---------------------------------------
                                       y            z             y      
                                  instrumental     OLS           OLS     
                                    variable                             
                                     IVREG     First STage  Second Stage 
                                      (1)          (2)           (3)     
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    z                               3.999***                             
                                    (0.015)                              
                                                                         
    a                                            0.137***                
                                                 (0.002)                 
                                                                         
    x                               2.991***      0.002       2.991***   
                                    (0.007)      (0.006)       (0.024)   
                                                                         
    first_stage_pred                                          3.999***   
                                                               (0.053)   
                                                                         
    Constant                        2.103***    -0.772***     2.103***   
                                    (0.120)      (0.105)       (0.420)   
                                                                         
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    Observations                      100          100           100     
    R2                               1.000        0.985         0.995    
    Adjusted R2                      1.000        0.985         0.995    
    Residual Std. Error (df = 97)    1.054        0.879         3.697    
    F Statistic (df = 2; 97)                   3,155.315*** 10,561.640***
    =====================================================================
    Note:                                     *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: I don't understand how this models the two stages separately? The dependent variable is y in bot equations

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated the answer accordingly.