# Getting first stage results from {AER}'s ivreg()

Tags: r

Is there a way to pull the first stage results from `ivreg()`? I'd like to see what the calculation looks like without running a separate regression.

Here's some code that includes an IV and how I would manually estimate the first stage along with a double check by following into the second stage.

```
library(AER)

y <- rnorm(100, 5, 10)
x <- rnorm(100, 3, 15)
z <- rnorm(100, 3, 7)
a <- rnorm(100, 1, 7)
b <- rnorm(100, 3, 5)

iv_fit <- ivreg(y ~ x + a  |
                a + z)


first_fit<-lm(x~a+z)

second_fit<-lm(y~first_fit$fitted.values+a)
summary(second_fit)
summary(iv_fit)
```

Comment: Did you manage to fine a way to obtain the first step results?

Comment: @Bob I didn't, but it also stopped being a priority. I believe there are more flexible commands that are newer than AER::ivreg(), so I'll probably pivot to something new once I have to do this again.

Comment: I see. Do you have any package suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coef(..., component = "stage1")`, `vcov(..., component = "stage1")`, and `confint(..., component = "stage1")` for the estimated coefficients and   corresponding variance-covariance matrix and confidence intervals from the stage-1 regression (only for the endogenous regressors).

Use `residuals(..., type = "stage1")` for the residuals from the stage-1 regression (only for the endogenous regressors).

For the t-statistic and p-value of first stage:

```
## extract components from ivreg stage 1
c1 = coef(m1, component = 'stage1')
v1 = vcov(m1, component = 'stage1')
se1 = sqrt(diag(v1))
t1 = c1/se1
p1 = 2*pt(-abs(t1),df=m1$df.residual1)
```

[Source](https://github.com/zeileis/ivreg/commit/2b49ec83968715c446f37046e40f1eeae3d0ae14).